# Create mobile navigation header in WordPress with custom settings

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to create a header in WordPress that only shows for mobile devices, and how to modify properties of that header from the dashboard settings area.

I'm assuming I should be using the `wp_is_mobile();` function to test for mobile. I'm just a bit green on how to implement this in WordPress. My main questions are as follows:

1. I believe I need to hook into the wp_head or activate_wp_head action
   hook, is this correct?
2. I want to set colors for background and font colors in the dashboard
   settings area. How do I go about doing this?
3. Is this a plugin? Is it a function? This question is about the
   terminology I should be using.
4. Final question, where should I put this code? I'm sure it depends on
   a couple of the previous answers, which is why I asked it last.

Thanks for the help. I don't need specific code I just need to be pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what you're looking for in terms of the mobile specific header by replacing:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
```

with this:

```
<?php
if ( wp_is_mobile() ) :
    get_header( 'mobile' );
else :
    get_header();
endif;
?>
```

in the file that you want to have a mobile specific header. You'll need to create your custom header in `header-mobile.php` in your theme's directory.

Read more about `get_header()` at the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header. Read more about `wp_is_mobile()` at the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_is_mobile.

In terms of using the Theme Customization API, which allows you to set colors for background and font colors in the `wp-admin`, I recommend reading up at the WordPress Codex here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API

For the Theme Customization API, you should add that code in your `functions.php` file.

The correct terminology is entirely dependant upon what you're doing, but it sounds like you just need to write a few functions, no plugin needed.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Also, just as something to point out, caching could cause this to not work (the `wp_is_mobile()` portion of the header.)

Comment: Ok cool. Thanks for the full response! Could this be done without modifying the built in code, for if I wanted to do it to many sites without having to change many different files that might have their own customizations?

Comment: @Vap0r What exactly do you mean? You want to do this across many different themes?

Comment: Yes, I was wondering if instead of modifying the get_header() function if I could hook into it. I'm new to this, but wouldn't `add_action("get_header", "mobile_header")` or something similar work?

Comment: That would hook into the mobile header, but it wouldn't change the header that is displaying.

Comment: Is there a way to do that? Maybe an add_filter or something? I'll vote yours as the answer I was just kind of hoping there was a way to do this without taking code out. Just by adding it.

Comment: I think what you're really looking for is output buffering, which gets very, very complicated for what you're asking to do and is generally a bad idea to make use of unless you absolutely have to. This isn't taking any code out, it is adding code (an if/else statement) to handle the mobile specific version.

Answer (score -1):

I think U should use @media, for example:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.menu {
    margin-left: 0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer any of the OP's questions.

Comment: @media (max-width: 767px) {
.menu {
    display: none;
}
.mobile-menu {
    display: inline;
}

Comment: That still doesn't answer the question.

Comment: You're not wrong but you definitely didn't answer all of it. What if I don't have the telephone and address in the menu class? This won't sort it.